# Risk and vulnerability analysis for the spread of alien species

Tags: qgis, fme-form, distribution, species

Based on knowledge about the potential for proliferation of alien forests species we are looking at possibilities for modelling the process.

Inputs should be area for initial plants, wind, elevation, nature types. The model should run n model years. Output should be an surface (shapefile or raster) indicating the risk of spread for the species.

The input information to such a system should probably conform to the BAM model  after Peterson et al (2011) Ecological Niches and Geographic Distributions (MPB-49).
[image]

Species distribution analysis systems like [Lifemapper](http://lifemapper.org/) exists. An other example is [QSDM – Species Distribution Modelling for the QGIS Processing Toolbox](https://conservationecology.wordpress.com/qgis-plugins-and-scripts/qsdm/).

The mentioned systems are not only providing the libraries but also providing interfaces to the actual computation system. A system would typically look like this:

[image]

We are most interested in the "black box" in the above setup. In particular the web front end could make things unnecessary complicated. Interfacing properly with GIS tools is a better start.

Does anyone have experience which points to how one of the above or other systems could serve as proof of concept. An answer should include reference to:

- Plugins, software or libraries website with documentation
- Papers, reports or blogs giving the use a proper context
- Information about license status

Comment: Lots of software can accomplish this - do you have a workflow in mind for how you want to combine / overlay / analyze and otherwise process these datasets? Sometimes having your project outlined first helps not only the focus of the task, but alleviates the hindrance of dedicating yourself to a particular software stack before you even begin...